# fileExistsAtPath doesn't work with a localhost URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url

I have an URL file located in the WebServer folder of my Mac.

When I want to read the file like this with my localhost (http://192.168.1.95), it works:

```
NSURL *numberOfAccounts = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.95/NumberOfAccounts"];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:numberOfAccounts encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",text); // it works
```

But when I want to check if the file exists, that always return `NO`:

```
BOOL isDir;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:numberOfAccounts.path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
NSLog(@"Yes"); // never call
```

I tried with `.path` or `.absoluteString`, with the direct NSString `@"http://192.168.1.95/NumberOfAccounts"`, with the function `fileURLWithPath`, but it doesn't work and I don't understand because the path in the NSLog is the same as when I want to read the file.

Furthermore, I think I have the same path problem when I want to list the contain of a folder, because my NSSMutableArray is empty with this:

```
NSMutableArray *allFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.95"] includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil]];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`fileExistsAtPath` works only with local file system paths (`file://` scheme, starting with `/`), this is also the reason why there is no `fileExistsAtURL` method.

Comment: Well, so how can I check if my file exists ?

Comment: Either with `URLSession` (HTTP or FTP access) or mount the server volume then you can use `fileExistsAtPath`.

Comment: I don't actually understand but I will try to reflect about your answer, thanks.

Maybe have you got an explanation why my `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` doesn't work too ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between file URLs and all other kinds of URLs.

For example, HTTP is a protocol for communicating with another program, a server. The response you get from it can be dynamic. That is, the server can do ***anything*** a program can do in response to your request. Even if it successfully provides data to you, that does not mean any particular "file" "exists". The server may have generated that data from scratch or synthesized it from other data.

There is, in general, no way to check if the server will successfully provide you data for a particular request other than by asking it to.

For this reason, there are a number of methods of `NSURL`, or methods of other classes that accept `NSURL`s as parameters, which only work for local `file:` URLs, not for other types of URLs.

A URL string (such as the `absoluteString` property) is **never** a valid file path, even for file URLs.

For your specific URL, `numberOfAccounts.path` is the same as `@"/NumberOfAccounts"`. That is, it's the path *portion* of the URL. Significant information, like the fact that one needs to use HTTP to access it and the host that provides it, is not included. If you attempt to perform file operations on that path, it will attempt to access a file called "NumberOfAccounts" at the root of your local machine's file system. It's unlikely there is such a file and, even if there were, it's not the same as whatever you would access via the URL.

As with your other misunderstandings, your attempt to treat `http://192.168.1.95` as though it were the parent directory of `http://192.168.1.95/NumberOfAccounts` is confused. It is not a directory of any kind. It's just a host and a scheme. The HTTP server at that host *may* provide **an HTML document** showing a file listing (for example, if you were to visit that URL in a web browser), but an HTML document is not a directory.

You could try to check if the server would provide data for a particular request by doing a HEAD request. Here's some untested code that should work:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:numberOfAccounts];
request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    if (response.statusCode == 200)
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        // failure
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Note that the above is asynchronous. The answer won't be known immediately after the code executes. Rather, the completion handler will be run some time later, once the communication with the server has completed. You have to structure your own code to cope with that.

Comment: Ok I understand this thing, thank you !

So to check if a file exists it's ok, but now how can I enumerate or store a list of files (like contentsOfDirectoryAtPath or enumeratorAtPath), with an URL (always with my WebServer) ?

Comment: You can't. Web servers don't work that way. FTP servers do, but that's not necessarily a good approach for security. Similarly, file servers like SMB or AFP servers can provide a way to access files on a server as part of your file system.

Comment: It is impossible ? But I don't see other ways... For example, you have many files in a folder which each one is named by a country name (their contain are empty, the file sizes 0 octet). And you want to list these countries on a NSMutableArray, but you don't know neither the file names nor the number of files (because people can add or delete file at any moment). So how can you list them ?

Comment: Web servers are not file servers. You have to stop imagining they are. They can't easily be used as file servers. They don't provide the ability to enumerate directory listings. Etc. If you want a file server, run a file server, not a web server.

Comment: Hello again Ken Thomases. I run my FTP server, so I can access to the server with the NSURL method. But with this way I can't manage my files because there isn't a method as enumeratorAtPath with NSURL. I misunderstand something... I have to use these methods (enumeratorAtPath, contentsOfDirectoryAtPath), but I can't with NSURL method (or maybe it exist equivalent methods ?). So how can I do this ?

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned FTP. I wasn't recommending that you use FTP. I just referred to it to make the distinction between it and HTTP(S). You **can** get directory listings via FTP using the `CFStream` API, but a) it's pretty broken, and b) it's deprecated. See [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97469). You might be able to use WebDAV to use a web server like a file server. You would have to use a third-party library (or write your own) to handle the WebDAV protocol, though. I'm not aware of any built-in APIs for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok so use WebDAV instead of FTP, I know nothing about this protocol but I will work on it... That seems me very strange because most of the applications have to transfer files through a server, which seems to be easily first, and finally it seems to be very complex..